# Sort buttons in alphabetical order

Tags: android, sorting, button

I created 5 buttons dynamically in a LinearLayout vertically. They get their names from string resources in 3 different languages. Therefore the buttons aren't always in the correct alphabetical order. So there's my question. What can i do to make the buttons being sorted alphabetically in all 3 languages?

```
Language 1:
String 1 = a,
String 2 = b,
String 3 = d,
String 4 = e,
String 5 = c,

Language 2: 
String 1 = c,
String 2 = e,
String 3 = a,
String 4 = b,
String 5 = d,

Language 3: 
String 1 = d,
String 2 = c,
String 3 = a,
String 4 = b,
String 5 = e,
```

Here's my code:

```
    Button btn1 = new Button(this); 
    btn1.setText(R.string.String1); 
    layout.addView(btn1);

    Button btn2 = new Button(this); 
    btn2.setText(R.string.String2); 
    layout.addView(btn2);

    Button btn3 = new Button(this); 
    btn3.setText(R.string.String3); 
    layout.addView(btn3);

    Button btn4 = new Button(this); 
    btn4.setText(R.string.String4); 
    layout.addView(btn4);

    Button btn5 = new Button(this); 
    btn5.setText(R.string.String5); 
    layout.addView(btn5);
```

Sincerely
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your buttons in a TreeMap (which is a sorted map):

```
Map<String, Button> map = new TreeMap<String, Button>();

Button btn1 = new Button(this); 
btn1.setText(R.string.String1); 
map.put(R.string.String1, btn1);

Button btn2 = new Button(this); 
btn2.setText(R.string.String2); 
map.put(R.string.String2, btn2);

Button btn3 = new Button(this); 
btn3.setText(R.string.String3); 
map.put(R.string.String3, btn3);

Button btn4 = new Button(this); 
btn4.setText(R.string.String4); 
map.put(R.string.String4, btn4);

Button btn5 = new Button(this); 
btn5.setText(R.string.String5); 
map.put(R.string.String5, btn5);

for (Button b : map.values()) {
    layout.addView(b);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the application crashes. Is there something missing maybe?

Comment: I found out that the btn1, btn2, btn3, etc. in the loop aren't associated with the btn1, btn2, btn3, etc. of the rest of the activity. How can i change that?

Comment: I am not an Android expert, but if your initial code works (apart from the order) then this should work too. Have you kept the `Button btn1 = new Button(this);` and `btn1.setText(R.string.String1);` statements for each button, before adding them to the map?

Comment: Also, it seems `btn.getText()` returns a `CharSequence`, so you might need to change the map lines to: `map.put(btn1.getText().toString(), btn1);`.

Comment: Yes, in fact i didn't delete Button btn1 = new Button(this); and btn1.setText(R.string.String1);
Now it's deleted, but the application still throws a NullPointerException.
In map.put(btn1.getText().toString(), btn1); i now use string variables for each button.
I think the problem must be the loop, because the activity throws a NullPointerException.
Do i have to make a loop for each button?

Comment: I also set layout params for each button. Is that the problem maybe?

Comment: @JohnD I have amended my answer to post a code equivalent to your original code but that will add the buttons in alphabetical order. If your original code works what I posted should work too.

Comment: @JohnD If it still does not work, I suggest you post a new question with your new code.

Comment: It tried and tried and tried... and suddenly... it works. :)) I don't know what was wrong with my code, but your code is perfect. Thank you! Unfortunately now i have another problem. I used margin for each button. Now that they are always sorted new, the margin is messed up. Is there a way to set a standard margin between each button?

Comment: @JohnD To be honest I have no idea! You should post a new question with regards to your margin issue. ps: if the answer solved your issue, you can accept it. You can read about [how accepting answers works and why it is important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179508).

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add(getString(R.string.String1));
strings.add(getString(R.string.String2));
strings.add(getString(R.string.String3));
strings.add(getString(R.string.String4));
strings.add(getString(R.string.String5));

for (String str : Collections.sort(strings)) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(str);
    layout.addView(b);
}
```

`TreeMap` is a decent option but seems excessive to me, unless you for some reason need to specifically track each button/string combination in a certain order in code.